# Convert a string into four different columns of a dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Everyone, I am new to Spark (programming to be honest) and I need some help with the below scenario.  My input file is having data in below format.
    Portnumber-UserID “ GET \ ..”
    Portnumber-UserID “ GET \ ..”

For each user we will have two rows of data. Each row contains only one string (spaces included) but with no proper delimiter

Example Inputs:

```
192.167.56.1-45195 “ GET \docsodb.sp.ip \..”
192.167.56.1-45195 “ GET \https://<url> \..”
238.142.23.5-24788 “ GET \docsodb.sp.ip \..”
238.142.23.5-24788 “ GET \ https://<url>  \..”
30.169.77.213-16745 “ GET \docsodb.sp.ip \..”
30.169.77.213-16745 “ GET \ https://<url> \..”
```

For the above data I would require output in below format, probably a dataframe.

```
Portnumber      UserID  URL             division_string
192.167.56.1    45195   https://<url>   docsodb.sp.ip
238.142.23.5    24788   https://<url>   docsodb.sp.ip
30.169.77.213   16745   https://<url>   docsodb.sp.ip
```

Can we achieve this through RDD transformations or we have to go with Spark SQL (through SQL queries). Also if this can be achieved either way could you please explain which one is a better approach?

Comment: Hey, if you will take a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You will see that `split()` uses the regular expression for splitting and not the actual delimiter. This means that You can technically split Your data into 4 columns as You want it, but the regular expression can be quite hard to tweak to match all the cases. I have assumed that You are using Java/Scala, if this is python then not sure if it's still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prepare the data and run spark-shell

```
cat <<-EOF >in
192.167.56.1-45195 “ GET \docsodb.sp.ip \..”
192.167.56.1-45195 “ GET \https://<url> \..”
238.142.23.5-24788 “ GET \docsodb.sp.ip \..”
238.142.23.5-24788 “ GET \ https://<url>  \..”
30.169.77.213-16745 “ GET \docsodb.sp.ip \..”
30.169.77.213-16745 “ GET \ https://<url> \..”
EOF

spark-shell
```

Now inside spark-shell we'll load the data from text file into a DataFrame, then parse it based on regexp capture group, finally group by Portnumber and UserId to get both division_string and URL on a single line, all using DataFrame API.

```
import spark.implicits._

// Load data
val df = spark.read.format("text").load("in")

// Regexp to parse input line
val re = """([\d\.]+)-(\d+) “ GET \\ ?([^\s]+)"""

// Transform
df.select(regexp_extract('value, re, 1).as("Portnumber"),
          regexp_extract('value, re, 2).as("UserId"),
          regexp_extract('value, re, 3).as("URL_or_div"))
  .groupBy('Portnumber, 'UserId)
  .agg(max(when('URL_or_div.like("https%"), 'URL_or_div)).as("URL"),
       max(when('URL_or_div.like("docsodb%"), 'URL_or_div)).as("division_stringL"))
  .show

+-------------+------+-------------+---------------+
|   Portnumber|UserId|          URL|division_string|
+-------------+------+-------------+---------------+
|30.169.77.213| 16745|https://<url>|  docsodb.sp.ip|
| 192.167.56.1| 45195|https://<url>|  docsodb.sp.ip|
| 238.142.23.5| 24788|https://<url>|  docsodb.sp.ip|
+-------------+------+-------------+---------------+
```

Anwering your last question DataFrame API or Spark SQL is preferred over RDD operations, unless you need low-level control over the processing. See [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) for more info.